# Can flymake or flycheck mark in dired (or in buffer lists) files with errors?

Tags: buffers, dired, flycheck, flymake

It would be nice if, in addition to flymake/flycheck marking errors in particular files, they could somehow mark files with errors in dired (or maybe just in the open-buffers list).

The goal would be to look at a whole list of files/buffers and be able to see which one have errors, and which ones are "clean".  (The Atom editor, for example, has a feature like this.)

Does anyone know of packages that offer this feature?

If not, does anyone have thoughts about how this might be implemented?  Or know of good resources for learning to build dired or buffer-list "plugins"?

Comment: Good question. Marking files in Dired not only lets you see them easily. It also lets you act on them in any number of ways.

Answer (score 1):

`diff-hl-dired-mode` in the [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) package certainly has the desired fringe display. Indicating errors on only opened files may be straight forward. Running flycheck on unopened files would probably present a bigger challenge. Anyway, maybe the buffer list approach is the best after all! :-)